# Error: object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found - even with changed variable name

Tags: r

I got this code to work:

```
mean<-aggregate(Listings.Recode$Price~Listings.Recode$Region, dataframe, mean)
```

However, I realized my variable name was the same as the "mean" function so I tried to re-name.  When I do so:

```
Listing.Mean<-aggregate(Listings.Recode$Price~Listings.Recode$Region, dataframe, mean)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, as literally all I'm doing is re-naming the variable.

Comment: If you are using the formula method, then it should be `aggregate(Price ~ Region, Listings.Recode, mean)`  It is not clear what `dataframe` object is in your code

Answer (score 4):

Well I'll be damned.  I found a solution.

```
rm(mean)
```

Comment: It seems like, then, that the problem was that you had two objects named `mean` in the global environment. In your second `aggregate` call, it was trying to apply your `data.frame` called `mean` not the `function` named `mean`